# CUDA C returns indeterminate and weird result without -G option on K20

Tags: c, cuda, printf, race-condition

I have the problem that my code returns incorrect result without -G option on K20. The original code is too complicated, so I simplify it to easy read and test. In order to keep the incorrect result when reduce the code, some statements looks weird, for example:

```
r_rhs2 = (r_p - r_p)-r_c;
```

if I replace it as

```
r_rhs2 =-r_c;
```

the possbility of making incorrect result will much less. The code fisrt assign 3 arrays(2D,in*jn) at host, and then cudaMemcpy to device, and next start the kernal "test<<>>" to do some calculations. Here is the most simplified code:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define in 16
#define jn 16
#define N0 (in*jn*3)
#define N1 (in*jn)

           double  h_dt, ***h_w;
__device__ double  d_dt,   *d_w;



__global__ void test()
{
  int id0,nn;
  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  double r_a, r_b, r_c, r_rhs1, r_rhs2;

  nn = 1;
  id0 = j*in + i;       //id0 is the ID of element in an array
  r_a = d_w[     id0];  //d_w[id0] is the first array
  r_b = d_w[  N1+id0];  //d_w[N1+id0] is the second array
  r_c = d_w[2*N1+id0];  //d_w[2*N1+id0] is the third array

  if (r_b <= 0.0){           //some calculation
    r_rhs1 = 0.0;            //
  }else{                     //
    r_rhs1 =-((r_c)/nn)*r_b; //the "()" increase the error rate
  }

  if(abs(r_b+r_a)>1.e20)printf("weird result=%e,%e,%e,%d,%d\n", r_b+r_a, r_b, r_a, i, j);  //one of the two printf statement, I show the result later that sometimes r_b+r_a is a large number while r_b and r_a are normal

  if (r_b+r_a <= 0.0){          //some calculation
    r_rhs2 = 0.0;               //
  }else{                        //
    r_rhs2 = (r_a - r_a) - r_c; //(r_a - r_a) increase the error rate
  }

  d_w[  N1+id0] = d_w[  N1+id0]+r_rhs2;  //update d_w
  d_w[2*N1+id0] = d_w[2*N1+id0]+r_rhs1;
}

                     
                     
double *** C_mymalloc(int d4, int d3, int d2)
{
  double ***a       = (double ***)malloc(sizeof(double)*d4*d3*d2 + sizeof(double *)*d4*d3 + sizeof(double **)*d4);
  double  **start_l = (double **)a + d4;
  double   *start_k = (double *)a  + d4 + d4*d3;
  int  k, l;


  for (l = 0; l < d4; l++){
    a[l] = start_l + l*d3;
    for (k = 0; k < d3; k++){
      a[l][k] = start_k + l*d3*d2 + k*d2;
    }
  }
  return a;
}


int main()
{
  double *w_m;
  int i,j,n;

  h_w = C_mymalloc(3,jn,in);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&w_m, sizeof(double)*N0);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_w, &w_m, sizeof(double *));

  for (j = 0; j <= jn-1; j++){
    for (i = 0; i <= in-1; i++){
      h_w[0][j][i] = 1.0;
      h_w[1][j][i] = 0.0;
      h_w[2][j][i] = 1.0/(i*i+j*j+1.0) - 1.0/((i-in)*(i-in)+(j-jn)*(j-jn)+1.0);  //no infinite number
    }
  }
  cudaMemcpy(w_m, h_w[0][0],  N0*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 dim_G(1 , 1 );
  dim3 dim_B(16, 16);

  n=0;

  while (n<=10){

    test<<<dim_G, dim_B>>>();

    printf("n=%d\n",n);

    n = n + 1;

    h_dt = 1.0;                                    //Though nonsense, 
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_dt, &h_dt, sizeof(double)); //the weird result
  }                                                //disappear without
                                                   //the two statement

  free(h_w);

  return 0;
}
```

My device: K20; CUDA5
compile command: nvcc main.cu -lm -o exe -arch compute_35 -code sm_35; cuda-memcheck ./exe;typical result:

```
n=0
n=1
n=2
n=3
n=4
n=5
n=6
n=7
n=8
dsa=3.741112e+117,-1.938073e-01,1.000000e+00,0,6
dsa=3.449943e+222,-1.859864e-01,1.000000e+00,1,6
dsa=-5.398272e+183,-1.681859e-01,1.000000e+00,2,6
dsa=3.317999e+214,-6.978805e-02,1.000000e+00,6,6
dsa=-2.596131e+264,-4.906721e-02,1.000000e+00,7,6
dsa=-3.011521e+154,-3.072307e-02,1.000000e+00,8,6
dsa=3.665153e+35,0.000000e+00,1.000000e+00,10,6
dsa=5.476628e+246,1.271596e-02,1.000000e+00,11,6
dsa=4.741912e+222,4.596547e-02,1.000000e+00,15,6
n=9
n=10
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Some other aspects:

1. not every run makes incorrect result, about 50% probability.
2. if -G option is added, the result is correct(might be due to not enough times test)
3. if __syncthread() is added, the result is correct
4. if I run the code on C2050, and compile command convert to: nvcc main.cu -lm -o exe -arch compute_20 -code sm_20, the result is correct

Comment: The first things that come to mind as possible reasons are (1) race condition (2) uninitialized variable (3) access out of bounds. As a first step, I would suggest adding status checks to all CUDA API calls and kernel launches, and running `cuda-memcheck` bounds checker, race checker, and API checker. You may also want to initialize all arrays of floating-point data with 0xff, which results in a NaN pattern.

Comment: I've run your code quite a few times, compiled exactly as you did, and have no problems.  I've run with `cuda-memcheck` and also with `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck` and there are no issues reported.  I never get the "weird result =" output (your output shows "dsa=" but your posted code has no such printout.) The problem might be specific to your system.  If you're not using CUDA 7, try upgrading to CUDA 7.  If your K20 has ECC mode off, try turning it on.  And certainly you should try running with `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: I run with cuda -memcheck, and the result remains. I am using CUDA5,  I will try CUDA7 right now. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I compiled the code, exactly as posted, with CUDA 6.5 for sm_20. I ran it 10 times in a row and did not see any issues. This is a default build, i.e. release mode / optimized. cuda-memcheck does not report any errors.

Comment: I give up CUDA5.0 and try CUDA5.5(only CUDA5 and CUDA5.5 exist, I am not the root) on K20, the weird results disappear!!! So there is a strong indication that CUDA5.0 cause the problem and the higer version (>=CUDA5.5) work fine. Still I dont know why?

Comment: It might be a bug in CUDA 5.0.  That compiler is several years old.  There are occasionally bugs and they do occasionally get fixed in newer versions.  Why don't you give an answer to explain what you did to fix it (yes, you can answer your own question).  That may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved when update CUDA5.0 to CUDA5.5(I have not tried higher version). Still I donot know the reason. According to Robert Crovella, it might be a bug in CUDA5.0. Whatever, CUDA5.5 works fine. Special thanks to njuffa and Robert Crovella.